# Installing magisk with Android 11

Tags: magisk, android-11

Is there a problem with, or something missing from, the steps at [this guide](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/root-android-11-using-magisk-0318066/) for installing Magisk on Android 11?

Specifically, in step 13, it says to flash the patched boot image (patched by Magisk Manager) to the phone, with

```
fastboot flash boot patched_magisk.img
```

followed by

```
fastboot reboot
```

And then to verify root in step 14 by checking in the Magisk Manager app. But doesn't step 13 reset the phone, so the installed apps like Magisk Manager are also gone?

Comment: unless you set *preserve force encryption* in advanced settings (before patching) step 13 does break encryption, therefore you are right userdata partition must formatted in order to work unencrypted on next boot. that is in fact a factory reset and the reason why magisk manager must installed twice. But repeating every step is unnecessary, once the boot.img is flashed your device is rooted. the tutorial has mentioned in step 6 *'leave both "Preserve" options enabled'* (you probably overlooked)

Comment: Thanks @alecxs ; I'm not sure if this was the reason in my case, as I am 99% sure I left the Preserve option enabled (the version of magisk manager I was using only had one preserve option, which is for force encryption). Also, after step 13 (the first time), with adb shell, I couldn't "su", it seemed like non-rooted. Anyway, then the 2nd time I did retry from step 6, but the patched image ended up being the same as the one from the 1st time (diff showed no difference), so I thought maybe I somehow messed up in the flashing step, Somehow, flashing the same patched image the 2nd time worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not. It's safe

All that you are doing in this step is to

- Check if your device is recognized in fastboot mode by `fastboot devices`
- Replace the boot image by the patched boot image on your computer by
  `fastboot flash boot xxx.img`.
- `fastboot reboot` will boot you into OS where you can verify root as next step recommends.

This the normal way of rooting using patched images and will not affect your installed apps. See [Magisk official documentation](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I did something wrong the first time. When I tried it again a second time, it was working as expected.